# How do intercept specific interface in java?

Tags: java, ejb

In `MyInterceptor`, which interface, `Ifclocal` or `IfcRemote`, invoked the method `doStuff` in `MyEjb`? It's possible know through which "channel" your bean was called? 
I need know which dependency injection invoked the  method.

```
@Local
public interface IfcLocal {
void doStuff(String s);
}

@Remote
public interface IfcRemote {
  void doStuff(String s);
}

@Stateless
@Interceptors({ MyInterceptor.class })
public class MyEjb implements IfcLocal, IfcRemote {
  @Override
  public void doStuff(String s) {
     System.out.println(s);
  }
}

public class MyManagedBean {
  @EJB private ifcLocal ifcLocal;
  @EJB private IfcRemote ifcRemote;

  public void go() {
    ifcLocal.doStuff("xxx");
    ifcRemote.doStuff("xxx");
  }
}

public class MyInterceptor {
  @AroundInvoke
  public Object intercept(InvocationContext inv) throws Exception {
    // ??? who invoked ???
    System.out.prinln(inv.getTarget().getClass()); // print MyEjb 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: if a method of a local interface, so I may have to clone some parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `@Resource private SessionContext sessionContext;` in `MyInterceptor`. After: `Class<?> interfaceReference = sessionContext.getInvokedBusinessInterface()`.